# AWS ec2 Postgres error after changing instance type

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2, psql, bitnami

After i change my instance from c4.large to t3.small my postgres not able connect with postgres

Here is what i have tryed

```
bitnami@ip-172-31-6-11:~$ sudo -u postgres psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
        Is the server running locally and accepting
        connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

Im not able to access my database to take its backup

Comment: Bitnami Engineer here. Please ensure the PostgreSQL service is running by using the `/opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh` script or the `ps aux` command. If the service is not running, please try to start it or check its log in the `/opt/bitnami/postgresql` folder.

Comment: 1. sudo /opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh status

Cannot find any running daemon to contact. If it is running, make sure you are pointing to the right pid file (/var/run/gonit.pid)

Comment: 2. ps aux | grep postgres
postgres 21786  0.0  0.1 213592  6096 ? Ss 10:32   0:00 postgres: 11/main: checkpointer
postgres 21787  0.0  0.1 213492  5896 ? Ss 10:32   0:00 postgres: 11/main: background writer
postgres 21788  0.0  0.2 213492  9840 ? Ss 0:32   0:00 postgres: 11/main: walwriter
postgres 21789  0.0  0.1 213892  6688 ? Ss 10:32   0:00 postgres: 11/main: autovacuum launcher
postgres 21790  0.0  0.1  68400  4280 ?  Ss 10:32   0:00 postgres: 11/main: stats collector
postgres 21791  0.0  0.1 213892  6592 ? Ss 10:32   0:00 postgres: 11/main: logical replication launcher

Comment: 3. sudo cat postgresql.log  

postgresql 11:28:51.18 INFO  ==> ** Starting PostgreSQL **
pgaudit extension initialized
could not bind IPv4 address "127.0.0.1": Address already in use
Is another postmaster already running on port 5432? If not, wait a few seconds and retry.
could not create listen socket for "localhost"
could not create any TCP/IP sockets
could not create any TCP/IP sockets